# Can't call count on an array

Tags: php, laravel

I can't call count on an array, it's showing :

> count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements
>   Countable.

```
//dd(gettype($question->options));//This line displays: "array" 
$realQuestion->total_answers = count($question->options); //But this one is not working
```

Comment: `dd($question->options)` or `dump($question->options)` are giving :
`array:5 [▼
  0 => "A. Sont exprimées par les cellules présentatrices d'antigènes."
  1 => "B. Sont impliquées dans la présentation de peptides d'origine virale."
  2 => "C. Sont impliquées dans la présentation de peptides d'origine exogène."
  3 => "D. Fixent et présentent des peptides moins longs que ceux des molécules de classe II"
  4 => "E. Peuvent être identifiées uniquement par des techniques sérologiques."
]`

Comment: sometimes the `dd` converts the param to array .. instead of dd, use the var_dump and show us the output please

Answer (score 2):

If you are calling relationship **use count of eloquent**.

Try to use this count it may help you.

```
$question->options->count();
```

Comment: You don't *have* to convert a `Collection` to an `array` before calling `count()` on it; `count($question->options);` will work just fine. But you're right that at that point, you might as well just use `->count();`.

Comment: Thank you @TimLewis Misunderstood some concept. Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved, the instruction was in a loop and the real parameter given to count that causes the error wasn't an array.

Answer (score -1):

Try using [the "count" aggregate method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-aggregates) instead:

```php
    <h6 style="color:teal"><?php echo $question->options->count(); ?></h6>
```